# MySQL Making an exception to an ORDER?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this query below.

```
SELECT name, id, note_date, note
FROM example
ORDER BY name, note_date
```

Lets say I have a user named "John Smith".   I want the query to work as is, except I want all entries by John Smith to violate the order and appear at the top of the list.

I was just wondering if there's a simpler or more proper way to do this other than a JOIN (like below).

Also, if it matters, "John Smith" may or may not have entries at any given time.

Thanks!

Like:

```
SELECT name, id, note_date, note
FROM example
WHERE name = "John Smith" 
ORDER BY note_date
JOIN
SELECT name, id, note_date, note
FROM example
WHERE name != "John Smith"
ORDER BY name, note_date
```

Comment: Why using JOIN here? UNION seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT name, 
             id, 
             note_date,
             note, 
             CASE 
               WHEN name= 'John Smith' 
                  THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
               END AS OrderStatement
 FROM example
 ORDER BY OrderStatement, name, note_date
```

Just you need to create one more column to generate custom order and use it in the ORDER BY clause along with the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> case when then

Such us

```
select id, etc, etc
    case users.name
        when ‘John Smith’ then ORDER BY etc
        when 'X' then ORDER BY etc
    end
from`users`
```

Pay attention to the vorgoles, these are not right, but I’m on my phone and there are not the right ones

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use UNION:

```
(SELECT name, id, note_date, note
FROM example
WHERE name = "John Smith" 
ORDER BY note_date)
UNION
(SELECT name, id, note_date, note
FROM example
WHERE name != "John Smith"
ORDER BY name, note_date)
```

Another, more concise way is to use CASE operator:

```
SELECT name, id, note_date, note, CASE WHEN name='John Smith' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as rank
FROM example
ORDER BY rank, name, note_date
```